# Spring JPA Single Transaction Manager with Two Entity Manager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I am using spring JPA and have xml configuration like

```
<!-- additional datasource end -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory1" />

<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory2" />

<bean
    id="org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory1" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceUnitName="primary">
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
        <!-- Map values-->          
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory2"        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceUnitName="primary">
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
        <!-- Map values-->          
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am declaring them in my repository class like this,

```
@Repository
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

@Autowired
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
private EntityManager em1;

@Autowired
@PersistenceContext(unitName ="secondary")
private EntityManager em2;
}
```

Where primary and secondry are datasources specified in `persistance.xml` file

I am using a method in which I am inserting in database1 and after that also updating in database2. For **insertion** I am using which **em1** and **updation** using **em2**. I am doing it in **same method** one line after another like,

```
line-1  >  totalUpdation = em1.createNativeQuery(INSERTION_QUERY).executeUpdate();
line-2  >  totalUpdation = em2.createNativeQuery(UPDATION_QUERY).executeUpdate();
```

Insertion works fine but when line-2 is executed with **em2** it gives `TransactionRequiredException : For update/delete query`.

Can anyone suggest **how can I use single TransactionManager with 2 Entity Managers** ?

Comment: What is this `p:qualifier-value=""` ?

Comment: @AlanHay : sorry , Its a typo  i have ignore , I have edited the ques